# CheckBox in Grid within ListBox Horizontal Alignment not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a `DataGrid` where I'm using a `RowDetailsTemplate` to Display detailed information for the selected `DataGrid` Item. The information being displayed are something like "SubItems" so I'm using a `ListBox` with a `TextBlock` and two `CheckBox` controls to display all the information.
The controls are positioned using a `Grid` but I'm not able to center the `CheckBox` controls within the `Grid`. They're always left aligned.
I've read several questions on Stackoverflow with similar problems but nothing worked for me. How can I center the two `CheckBox` controls to the `Grid.Column` they're assigned to? This is my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBox Name="lbDependencyDetails" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DependencyView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                               Text="{Binding Path=Dependency.SoftwareName}" 
                               Margin="{Binding Path=Margin}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                    <!--<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Width="2" />-->

                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Dependency.IsMarkedForReinstall, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              IsEnabled="False" 
                              Width="55" />
                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Dependency.IsMarkedForRepair, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              IsEnabled="False" 
                              Width="55" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ColumnDefinition` has set the width of column as 55 and width of rendered checkbox is also 55 so it will take the complete space. So Either change the `ColumnDefinition` to * or remove the width from Checkbox.

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBox Name="lbDependencyDetails" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DependencyView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                               Text="{Binding Path=Dependency.SoftwareName}" 
                               Margin="{Binding Path=Margin}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                    <!--<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Width="2" />-->

                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Dependency.IsMarkedForReinstall, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              IsEnabled="False" 
                              Width="55" />
                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Dependency.IsMarkedForRepair, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              IsEnabled="False" 
                              Width="55" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: that's it! thanks a lot! Can you help me to understand the problem a little bit better? If I set the Checkbox width to 55, what is it taking the complete space of? The Grid.Column?

Answer (score 1):

`Grid.column` is just for assigning the total width, so while you assigned the whole width as the width of the check box, at time of loading the UI it took up the whole space.